# Porting, Python to C# - How can I iterate a tuple over a tuple?

Tags: c#, python, 3d, porting

I'm port a Python project over to C#.

So far I've run into this problem, is there any way I could port this to C#?

```
verts = (-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
edges = (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,4),(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)

for edge in edges:
    for x,y,z in (verts[edge[0]],verts[edge[1]]):
        [...]
```

I've tried this,

```
verts.Add(new List<string> { "-1,-1,-1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "1,-1,-1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "1,1,-1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "-1,1,-1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "-1,-1,1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "1,-1,1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "1,1,1" });
verts.Add(new List<string> { "-1,1,1" });

edges.Add(new List<string> { "0,1" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "1,2" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "2,3" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "3,0" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "4,5" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "5,6" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "6,7" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "7,4" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "0,4" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "1,5" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "2,6" });
edges.Add(new List<string> { "3,7" });

foreach (List<string> vert in verts)
        {

            [...]
        }

        List<string> lines1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> lines2 = new List<string>();

        foreach (List<string> edge in edges)
        {
            int edge1 = int.Parse(edge[0].Split(',')[0]);
            int edge2 = int.Parse(edge[0].Split(',')[1]);

            int x;
            int y;
            int z;

            foreach (int vert in verts[edge1])
            {
                [...]
            }
        }
```

So now I am getting very confused, lot's of bugs, here any there.
I seems over complicated and impractical.

I hope someone can help me :)

If you need any more information, just leave a comment, If it's hard to read, again just leave a comment.

~Coolq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could go about doing it...

```
        var verts = new[]
        {
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (-1,-1,-1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (1,-1,-1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (1,1,-1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (-1,1,-1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (-1,-1,1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (1,-1,1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (1,1,1 ),
            new Tuple<int,int,int> (-1,1,1 )
        };
        var edges = new[]
        {
            new Tuple<int,int>(0,1),
            new Tuple<int,int>(2,2),
            new Tuple<int,int>(2,3),
            new Tuple<int,int>(3,0),
            new Tuple<int,int>(4,5),
            new Tuple<int,int>(5,6),
            new Tuple<int,int>(6,7),
            new Tuple<int,int>(7,4),
            new Tuple<int,int>(0,4),
            new Tuple<int,int>(1,5),
            new Tuple<int,int>(2,6),
            new Tuple<int,int>(3,7)
        };

        foreach(var edge in edges)
        {
            var edge1 = edge.Item1;
            var edge2 = edge.Item2;

            int x, y, z;//not sure why you need these?

            foreach(var vert in new[] { verts[edge1].Item1, verts[edge1].Item2, verts[edge1].Item3 })
            {
                //[...]
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is clear you've put time and effort into this, +1 from me :)

Also it's very clean and clear. So that's a check too ;)